# May I change fan speed manually in /sys on iMac?

Tags: lubuntu, mac, fan, fancontrol

I run Lubuntu 16.04 on a iMac 27" Mid 2010 i5. Fan control was fine until I had to swap the logicboard. Since then fans run at max. After trying a lot I found [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2156916&page=3) that someone recommended to change the maximum fan speed in /sys. I tried it and sometimes I was able to write to `fan1_min` and sometimes I was not able to write to it (as sudo).

I am not able at all to write to `fan1_max`.

I would like to set the maximum to a certain amount since I use Lubuntu just for things that do not make the iMac hot.